# Как сохранить таблицу HTML в базу данных MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Всем привет!
Скажите как сохранять таблицу с данными созданную с помощью JS в базу данных и потом ее оттуда выгружать в виде такой же таблицы?

Отдельные данные со страницы могу сохранять в БД, а вот как сохранить всю таблицу не знаю.

Comment: Какая разница-то? HTML - это обычный текст, вот и сохраняй его как текст.

Comment: Необходимо сохранить только HTML разметку в виде единого объекта или таблицу как структурированные данные?

Comment: @DenisI видимо сейчас ему подойдет вариант попроще))

Comment: Я пока не не знаю как правильнее.
Вот есть таблица, как ее сохранять с таблицу?
Отдельный текст я сохраняю в заранее созданную в БД ячейку, а вот как сохранить данные из таблицы, что бы потом еще их в такую же таблицу извлечь.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю что начать необходимо с извлечения данных из HTML таблицы и  представления их в виде структуры данных (объекта или массива) в JS. Далее можно будет построить нужный запрос к БД (или API).

Таблица может иметь различные представления в зависимости от контекста их использования.

1. На страничке : html .
2. В процессе  обработки данных: представление в виде JS структур, где нет лишних HTML элементов.
3. В БД представления будут специфичны в зааисимости от используемой БД.